# Intentando pasar una String como props en Vue pero se recibe un objeto

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Estoy haciendo una simple app de "lista de tareas" y quiero que cuando se pulse en el botón "Añadir", aparezca abajo lo que se está escribiendo en el input.

Para eso utilizo v-model en el input que están en el componente Parent (TodoList.vue) y luego v-bind en el componente `<TodoItem v-bind:titulo_item={titulo_item} />` (porque lo que aparecerá en pantalla es un h6 que está en el componente Child, no en `TodoList.vue` )

Así es como lo tengo organizado:

TodoList.vue (componente Parent)

```js
<template>
  <div class="todo-list-wrapper">
    <div class="mt-2 first-wrapper">
    <b-form-input v-model="titulo_item" placeholder="añade alguna cosa... "></b-form-input>
    <b-button v-on:click="newItem" pill variant="primary">Añadir</b-button>
    </div>
  <TodoItem v-bind:titulo_item={titulo_item} />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import TodoItem from "./TodoItem"
export default {
    name: 'TodoList',
    components: {
        TodoItem
    },
    data () {
    return {
      titulo_item: "",
      itemEstaCreado: false
      }
    },
    methods: {
      newItem: function (){
      this.itemEstaCreado = true;
    }
    }
  }
</script>
```

TodoItem.vue (componente Child)

```js
<template>
  <h6 class="mb-0">{{titulo_item}}</h6>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'TodoItem',
    components: {
        
    },
    props: {
     titulo_item: {
      type: String,
     }
    }
}
</script>
```

El problema es si escribo en el `<b-form-input v-model="titulo_item" placeholder="añade alguna cosa... "></b-form-input>` "manzanas", no me aparece en el `<h6 class="mb-0">{{titulo_item}}</h6>` "manzanas". Sino: `{ "titulo_item": "manzanas" }`

Literalmente, está cogiendo el objeto entero como una string, cuando sólo quiero que coja la string "manzanas".

Comment: Que versión de vue estas trabajando ?

Comment: La versión 2.6.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema viene dado principalmente a la manera de declarar tu `props` y la manera en que pasas el valor, a partir de `vue 2.0` la manera idónea de hacer esto es la siguiente;

**TodoList.vue (componente Parent)**

```
<template>
  <div class="todo-list-wrapper">
    <div class="mt-2 first-wrapper">
    <b-form-input v-model="titulo_item" placeholder="añade alguna cosa... "></b-form-input>
    <b-button v-on:click="newItem" pill variant="primary">Añadir</b-button>
    </div>
  <todo-item :titulo-item="titulo_item" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import TodoItem from "./TodoItem"
export default {
    name: 'TodoList',
    components: {
        TodoItem
    },
    data () {
    return {
      titulo_item: "",
      itemEstaCreado: false
      }
    },
    methods: {
      newItem: function (){
      this.itemEstaCreado = true;
    }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Nota la linea donde se usa el component que cambio de esto;

```html
<TodoItem v-bind:titulo_item={titulo_item} />
```

a esto:

```html
<todo-item :titulo-item="titulo_item" />
```

Segun las especificaciones de `vue 2` los nombre de componentes y props aunque los tengas en `UpperCalmelCase` debes llamarlos en tu `html` en `kebab-case`.

**TodoItem.vue (componente Child)**

```
<template>
  <h6 class="mb-0">{{titulo_item}}</h6>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'TodoItem',
    components: {

    },
    props: {
        tituloItem:String
    }
}
</script>
```

Se cambia tu `props` propiedad de esto:

```
props: {
      titulo_item: {
      type: String,
      }
    }
```

A esto:

```
props: {
        tituloItem:String
    }
```

Según las especificaciones de `vue 2` esta es la manera correcta de `tipar` las props que tendrá tu componente.

**Resumen**

Mi solución propuesta es cambiar la linea de uso del componente en tu html a;

`<todo-item :titulo-item="titulo_item" />`

y tus `props` a;

```
props: {
        tituloItem:String
    }
```

Comment: Genial me ha servido aunque te comento que sólo me funciona bien si cambio la primera parte. Si le pongo las props como me dices "tituloItem:String" entonces no me aparece nada.